# Rectangular div css

Tags: css

I want to use a rectangular background like the red part of the following image. How can I do it?

[image]

I would like to use a background something like

```
#trapezium {
  height: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  border-bottom: 100vh solid #ec3504;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this with 2 divs ( which i can see in your question that you have two separate elements ) . An make a shape from borders.

See more about css shapes here -> [the shapes of css](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)

```css
   .right {
     border-bottom: 200px solid red;
     border-left: 25px solid transparent;
     border-right: 0px solid transparent;
     height: 0;
     flex: 0 50%;
   }

   .left {
     flex: 0 50%;
   }

   .wrapper {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     display: flex;
     background: grey;
   }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbbbbb assssss sssssssssss
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    bbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbbbbb assssss sssssssssss
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to use it as a background. See my update.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use **linear-background**, maybe something like this one:

```css
.testBG
{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(115deg, #aaaaaa 50%, red 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="testBG"></div>
```

On the next examples, the color stops (percentages) are not equal just to emulate a smooth transition between colors, and the **angle** is changed too:

```css
.testBG
{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(100deg, #aaaaaa 50%, red 51%);
}
```

```html
<div class="testBG"></div>
```

```css
.testBG
{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(125deg, #aaaaaa 50%, red 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="testBG"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me a night.

Comment: Here is a little problem. The slope is not smooth. Any help?

Comment: You can play with the **color stops** (percentages) of the **linear-background** to emulate smooth transtition between the colors. I add a few more examples. Anyway, what you mean with the slope is not smooth, can you give me more details?